# Changing Tomcat Set-Cookie header

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Is there any way to change the Set-Cookie header to something other than JSESSIONID? To something like ASP.NET_SessionId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the name of the session cookie by [setting the `org.apache.catalina.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` system property](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/systemprops.html#Sessions).